# UiBinder Dynamic DockPanel

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Simple Question ....
If I have a StackLayoutPanel on the left, I want to click it  have a dynamically loaded
widget in my DockLayoutPanel on right ... similar to the GWt example
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Mail/Mail.html.. where clicking anything under mailboxes
would trigger a different widget on right...

Comment: Have you looked at the source for the Mail sample?  http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/mail/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mail -- it's pretty old code, but the basics of what's going on should be there.

Comment: Jason, I have... but it fails to answer the question, regarding the the StackLayoutPanel items dynamically the widget in one of the Dock Panel layout areas... all smoke and mirrors in that regard

Comment: really what you're asking is how to swap out one widget with another based on a click event, right?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use the specific widgets you're using, but this is the general idea.

```
public class Index implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // the panel that holds the content widgets
        final SimplePanel mainPanel = new SimplePanel();
        // the panel that holds the links
        FlowPanel leftPanel = new FlowPanel();
        // the first content widget
        final Label oneContent = new Label("one content");
        // the second content widget
        final Label twoContent = new Label("two content");
        // the anchor to load the first content widget when clicked
        Anchor one = new Anchor("one menu");
        // add the click handler to do the content swap
        one.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // remove any previous content
                mainPanel.clear();
                // add the first content widget
                mainPanel.add(oneContent);
            }
        });

        // the anchor to load the first content widget when clicked
        Anchor two = new Anchor("two menu");
        // add the click handler to do the content swap
        two.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // remove any previous content
                mainPanel.clear();
                // add the second content widget
                mainPanel.add(twoContent);
            }
        });

        leftPanel.add(one);
        leftPanel.add(two);
        // add everything to the RootPanel
        RootPanel.get().add(leftPanel);
        RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```